CORS nestjs et angular :
I have this proleme for a project with angular and nestjs :
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/card' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

The problem is that your nestJS backend does not have CORS enabled.
In your main.ts file, you should have something like this:
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
await app.listen(3000);

To add CORS to your application, add the line enabling CORS and provide an origin from which your backend will accept requests. The following code will allow requests from any origin:
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.enableCors({
    origin: "*"
});
await app.listen(3000);

However, if you want to use cookies within your app, you should configure the exact location. In your case, it is "http://localhost:4200":
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.enableCors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:4200"
  });
await app.listen(3000);


So i resolve it by:

npm install --save @nestjs/serve-static in the nest project
import ServeStaticModule in the appModule rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', 'client')
Replace 'client' with the path to your Angular build application
Add this line to enable CORS headers in the main.ts: app.enableCors();

